# Brightcove video player events for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, brightcove

**Need:** I want to get the onComplete event (like the answer here: [How to detect the end of a BrightCove Video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692706/how-to-detect-the-end-of-a-brightcove-video)) but not able to hook it up to the react version - the documentation link in the answer also returns a 404

**MVCE**:

- Using the codepen on https://player.support.brightcove.com/coding-topics/react-player-loader.html
- unable to get `onComplete` to fire, like success case is firing ( `onSuccess: function(success)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got this working;

- there is no `onComplete` (or even `onEnded` or `onFinsihed`) event anymore like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692706/how-to-detect-the-end-of-a-brightcove-video) on stackoverflow suggested
- we have to work within `onSuccess` function
- these links helped:

- https://player.support.brightcove.com/publish/brightcove-player-loader.html#Available_parameters

- complete list of events: https://docs.brightcove.com/brightcove-player/1.x/Player.html

relevant **JS**:

```
onSuccess: function(success) {
      var myPlayer = success.ref;
      myPlayer.on('ended',function(){
         console.log('video ended...');
      });
    },
```

complete [working codepen here](https://codepen.io/akberiqbal/pen/PoGJXgY)